# SQL Get last 7 days from event date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

The best way to explain what I need is showing, so, here it is:

Currently I have this query

```
select

date_
,count(*) as count_

from table 

group by date_
```

which returns me the following database

[image: QUERY RESULT]

Now I need to get a new column, that shows me the count off all the previous 7 days, considering the row date_.
So, if the row is from day 29/06, I have to count all ocurrencies of that day ( my query is already doing it) and get all ocurrencies from day 22/06 to 29/06

The result should be something like this:

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Which database are you using: mysql, postgresql, oracle...?

Comment: I am using Amazon AginityRedshift. I guess is uses Postgre (not sure)

Comment: @Miguel . . . Can you have gaps in the dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have values for all dates, without gaps, then you can use window functions with a `rows` frame:

```
select
    date,
    count(*) cnt
    sum(count(*)) over(order by date rows between 7 preceding and current row) cnt_d7
from mytable
group by date
order by date
```

Comment: Your answer works for 99% of my data. But sometimes I got no data on the weekends, and this logic is not considering it

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this:

```
select
    date_,
    count(*) as count_,
    (select count(*) 
        from table as b
        where b.date_ <= a.date_ and b.date_ > a.date - interval '7 days'
    ) as count7days_
from table as a
group by date_
```

Comment: It ended up beeing the best solution

Comment: @Miguel . . . Can you define "best"?  I would think the first version in my answer would have the best performance.

Comment: Your solution also worked. But, in the future, I am going to need to get a Distinct Count of the last 7 days. And I guess I am not able to do that using both versions of yours

Answer (score 2):

If you have gaps, you can do a more complicated solution where you add and subtract the values:

```
with t as (
      select date_, count(*) as count_
      from table 
      group by date_
      union all
      select date_ + interval '8 day', -count(*) as count_
      from table 
      group by date_
     )
select date_, 
       sum(sum(count_)) over (order by date_ rows between unbounded preceding and current row) - sum(count_)
from t;
```

The `- sum(count_)` is because you do not seem to want the current day in the cumulated amount.

You can also use the nasty self-join approach . . . which should be okay for 7 days:

```
with t as (
      select date_, count(*) as count_
      from table 
      group by date_
     )
select t.date_, t.count_, sum(tprev.count_)
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.date_ >= t.date_ - interval '7 day' and
        tprev.date_ < t.date_
group by t.date_, t.count_;
```

The performance will get worse and worse as "7" gets bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Try with subquery for the new column:

```sql
select

table.date_ as groupdate,
count(table.date_) as date_count,
(select count(table.date_)
   from table
   where table.date_ <= groupdate and table.date_ >= groupdate - interval '7 day'
) as total7

from table

group by groupdate
order by groupdate
```